HFSExplorer- Cant detect Hard drive 2012 Macbook Pro?
i have a 2012 Macbook Pro 2012 and need to get files off my old mac drive using Windows 7 but autodetect ect comes up  "no HFS+ file systems found"  i am using the latest version and Macbook uses "catalina"

Why not boot to macOS Catalina and then use SMB to transfer the files to another computer. Or just copy the files to a ExFAT formatted flash drive?

Catalina does not use HFS+ by default, it uses APFS.
Paragon make an interpreter - https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/ - though it's a bit expensive for a one-off use. I think it has a free trial which might be enough to test.

Thanks thats explains why it wwouldnt  read the drive. I dont know anything about Mac OS's.  i used HFS Explorer on an old 2004ish Mac and it read it great but the 2012 Pro not. SO That program only reads HFS+ ect OS? so which years or Models from 2004 to now has HFS or APFS? and also can you elect the type before you load your OS such as Catalina?

HFS+ was introduced with the Intel Macs & was used as the default format until High Sierra in 2017. Since then, it's all APFS. It's not the Mac that decides it, per se, it's the OS. Non-boot drives can be HFS or APFS [or even other formats, FAT etc] but the boot drive is now always APFS

If HFS+ was used up to 2017, why has my 2012 using APFS? Did certain models do this but most were HFS+?

"It's not the Mac that decides it, per se, it's the OS."

Yes thanks you mentioned that earlier.  Its a pain as the HFS Explorer can dig up deleted stuff like Recuva can but not APFS. Maybe Recuva will be for Mac one day and HFS explorer will also so all types or maybe thats a off limits licencing issue?  Anyway many thanks.

Just a follow up question. If i have a computer that is running and the Key activated and all good and i put another diff comp C drive into it even with same OS type, Will it only ask for "click" to activate or fully lock up and tell me to call MS as it detected wrong drive  and B,  If i dont ring or do anything but put the correct drive back in,  will it reactivate now and all be good again or stay deactivated?

I really have no idea - it's not an Apple question at all, it's a Windows thing.
